# Эффективное использование void*

Tags: c, c++

Могли бы вы перечислить случаи, в которых есть смысл использовать указатель на void?

Comment: Все случаи? Их многовато.

Например, в C если ваша структура данных должна работать с указателем на произвольный тип, вы просто пользуетесь `void*`, и возлагаете на пользователя необходимость приведения типов. Например, так реализован стандартный алгоритм [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort).

Comment: Да, это своего рода полиморфизм в С.

Comment: @strol, практически  все  обобщенное программирование, которое с С++ делается через templates в Си производится через `void \*` и макросы (`#define`).

Минус в этом - компилятор ничем не может помочь (реальных типов он просто не знает).

Плюс - не надо изощряться и писать много слов, чтобы объяснить компилятору некоторые очевидные для программиста вещи, которым компилятор не желает доверять.

Answer (score 2):

1) Передачи в функцию указателя на произвольный тип. Далее по какому-то признаку, дополнительному параметру (идентификатору типа) или используя RTTI понять что за объект прилетел и привести указатель к нужному типу.
2) Массив указателей на универсальные функции:

```
class MyClass { int i; };
typedef void *(*UniFunc)(void *);
void *PostHandler(void *data) { return (void *)0; }
void *GetHandler(void *data) { return (void *)0; }
UniFunc UniHandlers[] = { &PostHandler, GetHandler }; // амперсанд обязателен только для функций-членов
int main() {
    MyClass mc;
    UniHandlers[0] ((void *)&mc); // Вызов PostHandler с аргументом &mc
}
```

Для C++ Больше добавить нечего, в СИ его густо использует стандартная библиотека

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что приведенный код - это `c++`?

Comment: Да, это C++, правда упустил указатели на члены, но там ничего интересного кроме чудного синтаксиса. Здесь боюсь напортачить. Так что годаздо лучше покурить документацию

Comment: Это не валидный для `c++` код, т.к. типы аргументов не совпадают. А в исходном варианте и типы возвращаемых значений не совпадали.

Comment: Да действительно не доглядел! Тетерь валидный!